# How to getIntent().getData(); on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

My application uses login with twitter, the example code works using Activity
but I want my app to work using Fragment like this:

1. Click login with twitter button
2. Go to web browser for Authorize application
3. Back to application Feeds(use fragment) & show Toast twitter_id

How to edit error on `Uri uri = getIntent().getData();`

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
    
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData(); // <<<<<<<
    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(ConstantValues.URL_PARAMETER_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

       
    TwitterGet get=new TwitterGet();
    get.execute(verifier);
       
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: where you are using that fragment?

Comment: for that you are using startActivityforresult?

Comment: You can also use setarguments() and getarguments() method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Uri uri = getIntent().getData();` in the fragment, you just need call getActivity() first:

```
Uri uri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating the fragment  pass your extra with a key

In your fragment extract that extra by identifying with a key.For example

```
Bundle args = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
String value= args.getString("your key");
```